How to write a functional form in KDB+/Q with a present wildcard inside where clause?
As an example in a normal qSQL query we would write:
select from table where sym like "temp*"
To select any elements in the `sym column that start with "temp*" followed by any sequence of characters.
How would we write that in a functional form? It is purely for an assignment task that I'm completing which it requires me to re-write a function using functional form.
?[trade; enlist(like;`newCol;($:;enlist`ABC)); 0b; ()] this works well in the KX Academy Jupyter Notebook however, this does not take a wildcard into consideration.
My parsed select statement returns me this:
?
`table
,,(';(like;`sym);(*;`temp))
0b
()

However, I'm failing to understand how to write this, there's nothing I could find online. Please help.

Your parsed select statement is not correct - try the below to see.
q)parse"select from table where sym like \"temp*\""
That should give you a starting point to build the equivalent functional statement

Thank you. I should've known. Silly mistake.

When building your query you can use backslashes to escape the quote characters to allow your query to be parsed:
q)parse "select from table where sym like \"temp*\""
?
`table
,,(like;`sym;"temp*")
0b
()

which would be formed into:
?[table;enlist (like;`sym;"temp*");0b;()]

There is a nice script by kx which helps in forming functional selects:
https://code.kx.com/q/wp/parse-trees/#appendix

Thank you so much, I feel bit dumb for not knowing how to parse strings properly. This works perfect now, thank you.

When I run the statement:
parse"select from table where sym like \"temp*\""

I get:
?
`table
,,(like;`sym;"temp*")
0b
()

which equates to:
?[`table;enlist(like;`sym;"temp*");0b;()]

Are you sure you've parsed the initial statement correctly?

Thank you for your help and you were right yes! ^ above is the answer I sought after.
